# Javascript Insert after </a> Appears on Text

Tags: javascript, string, object

I'm a complete noob at this so I could have it totally wrong. What I want to do is insert the `XXXXXXXX` exactly after the first `</a>` appears on a post. I have tried converting the `</a>` characters, but I can't get it to work on any browser. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div expr:id="aim1" + data:post.id'/>
<div style='float:right; padding:0 0 10px 10px ;'>

XXXXXXXX

</div>


<div expr:id="aim2" + data:post.id'>

   <data:post.body/>

</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var obj0=document.getElementById("aim1<data:post.id/>");
var obj1=document.getElementById("aim2<data:post.id/>");
var s=obj1.innerHTML;
var r=s.indexOf("</a>");
if(r > 0) {obj0.innerHTML=s.substr(0,r);obj1.innerHTML=s.substring(r+3);}
</script>
</p>
```

Comment: `</a>` as in after an anchor tag, or `</a>` as in after a string containing "</a>"?

Comment: I said </a> because I want it to go immediately after the first image on a post. The code will be on the site's template.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="payload">
XXXXXXXX
</div>

<div id="target">
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
   Content within the target.
   <a href="">Anchor</a>
</div>
```

The following JavaScript code will move the `payload` div to after the first anchor tag within the `target` div.

```
function insertAfter(addition,target) {
    var parent = target.parentNode;

    if (parent.lastChild == target) {
        parent.appendChild(addition);  
    } else {
        parent.insertBefore(addition,target.nextSibling);
    }
}

var payload = document.getElementById("payload");
var target = document.getElementById("target");

var anchors = target.getElementsByTagName("a");

if (anchors.length > 0) {
    insertAfter(payload,anchors[0]);
}
```

[Tested @ jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/e4s79/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much Chuckx. Worked like a charm

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer (by clicking the check mark next to the answer).

http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask